# Testing with Hakyll's MonadMetadata

Tags: haskell, hspec, hakyll

For our Hakyll codebase, I've written a few helper methods and have started adding some HSpec unit tests around newer ones e.g.:

```
-- | Reject an item unless @fieldName@ is set to "true"
unlessEnabled :: MonadMetadata m
              => String
              -> Item a
              -> m Bool
unlessEnabled fieldName item = do
    maybeValue <- getMetadataBool (itemIdentifier item) fieldName
    return $ maybe True not maybeValue

-- | Try to look up a boolean field ("true" maps to @Just True@)
getMetadataBool :: MonadMetadata m
                => Identifier
                -> String
                -> m (Maybe Bool)
getMetadataBool ident name = do
    maybeString <- getMetadataField ident name
    return $ ((== "true") . map toLower) <$> maybeString
```

Now creating an `Item` or `Identifier` for testing is easy enough, but I'm not sure where to go with the [`MonadMetadata`](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/reference/Hakyll-Core-Metadata.html#t:MonadMetadata) when running an Hspec.

I've seen [`testCompiler`](https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/blob/1abdeee743d65d96c6f469213ca6e7ea823340a7/tests/TestSuite/Util.hs#L56) which feels like it might be copyable / useful ([`Compiler` has a `MonadMetadata` instance](https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/blob/1abdeee743d65d96c6f469213ca6e7ea823340a7/lib/Hakyll/Core/Compiler/Internal.hs#L173)), but I'm out of my Haskell-depth here...

Comment: You might want to test this with your own `MonadMetadata` instance, creating a whole `Compiler` or `Rules` value for this will be overly complicated.

Comment: Great - I started down that route (`newtype FakeMetadata` with lots of instances) but even that seemed a little aimless to me... I guess I need a `runFakeMetadata` or something?

Comment: I guess you could use a `Reader`-like data type for `MonadMetadata`, with a `Metadata` environment. For pattern matches, probably just ignore the pattern and always return an empty list. And yes, in the end you would want to `run` the reader with example objects.

Comment: Thanks. Haven't managed to work this out still though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually (and thanks to @Bergi's suggestions) I got something working, and then tidied up:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

type KeyedValuesOf a = [(String, a)]

-- | Create Metadata from basic list of key-values -- stolen from Hakyll itself.
meta :: Yaml.ToJSON a => KeyedValuesOf a -> Metadata
meta pairs = HMS.fromList [(T.pack k, Yaml.toJSON v) | (k, v) <- pairs]

-- | A 'Reader' class of our own, with a specialised environment
--   for key-value metadata pairs.
newtype MonadMetadataReader a =
    MonadMetadataReader {runMonadMetadataReader :: KeyedValuesOf String -> a}
        deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

-- | Simple 'Metadata' holder.
-- There are never any matches found,
-- and all metadata (for all items)
-- comes from from the Reader-like environment at setup.
instance MonadMetadata MonadMetadataReader where
    getMetadata identifier = MonadMetadataReader meta

    getMatches pattern = return []
```

Which allowed simple unit tests like:

```
it "enables for a value of \"false\"" $ do
    let enabled = runMonadMetadataReader (unlessEnabled "key" item) [("key", "false")]
    enabled `shouldBe` True

it "disables for a value of \"true\"" $ do
    let enabled = runMonadMetadataReader (unlessEnabled "key" item) [("key", "true")]
    enabled `shouldBe` False

it "enables if no metadata found" $ do
    let enabled = runMonadMetadataReader (unlessEnabled "key" item) []
    enabled `shouldBe` True
```